# ER DIAGRAM Drawing

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, dia

ok so here is the case study I got

> A student is enrolled in a subject during a semester and a year (e.g. John Smith is enrolled in the subject Python Programming in semester 1 in 2016).
> Students’ information is stored at the time when they enroll. To become a student, they must enroll in at least one subject.
> They must provide their mobile phone number (st_phone) at the enrolment.
> The enrolment status of a student can be: WD (withdrawn), ENR (enrolled), PRV (provisional enrolment)
> Subject information is stored with reference to a course (subject codes are unique to a course e.g. VIT1201 is the code for the subject: Database Systems belongs to VDIT course, ITD1009 is Java Programming subject belong to TDIT course)
> A teacher may teach and is responsible for a subject in a semester.
> The system needs to record, what subject is taught by a teacher in a given semester in a year.  For example, teacher Fiona Scott teaches Introduction to Databases in semester 1 of 2016. In semester 2, 2016 she taught Networking. She taught Databases again in Semester 1, 2017.
> For each teacher, the teaching day for a subject needs to be recorded.
> Teachers sometimes go on long service leave or do research and therefore may not teach in a particular semester or year.
> Some teachers act as mentors for 1 or more other teachers
> A teacher will only have one mentor
> Senior teachers do not have mentors.

and I have done this so far
[in DIA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG3VI.png)

now here are the questions
did I do the mentor,teacher relationship right so what I thought was a mentor can teach many teachers but a teacher can have only one mentor but the problem is with seniors
should i add teacher type or role to get senior and if yes where should i put it ?!

now another matter is I'm confused by the wording here it says " a student is enrolled in a subject during a sem and a year" does this mean year and sem should be in enrolment table or student table

Appreciate your time and answers ( i know it is a lot to read)

Comment: The mentor/teacher thing looks odd, if nothing else because they have different types

Comment: Additionally your making some fairly nasty assumptions about names there